# Windows Phone 8.1 Calendar Events

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app in Windows Phone 8.1 I want to add event in the  phone calendar. I could only find the SaveAppointmentTask, but that is only supported in windows phone 8 apps.Is there any alternative for it in windows 8.1. Please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631243.aspx

This will help you. Work with the appointments.